# How to get data from SQL server to a DataGridView then to Excel

Tags: .net, excel, c#-4.0

I have a function that gets data from a database then puts it into a grid.  I use the following code:

```
ds = new DataSet();
SQL = "SELECT * " +
    "FROM table ";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connect))
{
    conn.Open();
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn);
    adapter.Fill(ds, "data");
}

dgvInvoiceData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Which works well.  Sometimes the user may wish to copy the grid to Excel.  This works well  enough for small result sets.  Once they get past 50 rows it rapidly approaches unusable.  I tried setting a range to an array but this fails every time.

```
int cols = 0;
int rows;

_Application XL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
_Workbook workbook = XL.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
_Worksheet worksheet = null;
Range xlr;

XL.Visible = false;
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = sheetName;

xlr = worksheet.Range["A0:B02"];
xlr = worksheet.get_Range("A0:" + (char)(64 + cols) + rows.ToString());
xlr = worksheet.get_Range("A0:" + (char)(64 + cols) + rows.ToString(), Type.Missing);
worksheet.get_Range("A0:" + (char)(64 + cols) + rows.ToString(), Type.Missing).Value2 = dt;
```

There are many attempts to try to get a range then set an array to it or something similar.

I get some useless error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in AspireExcel.dll

If there is a better way to get the data to the grid where I could pass that data source directly to Excel or something I would be fine with that.

I don't know if this is related, but looking at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303872) I see the Excel variable defined slightly different.  When I tried it

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application XL = new Excel.Application();
```

I get

> The type or namespace name 'Excel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Excel   C:\Code\Excel\Excel\Transfer.cs 190 Active

Could I have the wrong reference(s)?  I have Microsoft.Office.Core & Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: Take a look at [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com), it is a pretty simple library which can be used to create Excel file without using Interop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish what you have asked.  It appears that you are somewhat familiar with using Excel Automation via the interop libraries, so here is a simplistic way to accomplish the task using that.

This method writes one row at a time from the `DataTable`.  This will not be as fast as copying the entire table to a 2D array and assigning it to an identically sized `Excel.Range`, but in many cases it is fast enough.  It uses the predefined DataRow.ItemArray directly as the source to assign to an `Excel.Range`.  The only inputs to the method are a `DataTable` and an `Excel.Range` that defines the starting cell address in an `Excel.WorkSheet`.

`using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

```
private void ExportDT(DataTable dt, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range topLeftCell)
{
    Excel.Range exportRange = topLeftCell.Cells.get_Item(1, 1) as Excel.Range;
    exportRange = exportRange.get_Resize(1, dt.Columns.Count);
    // create and export header
    List<string> header = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        header.Add(c.ColumnName);
    }
    exportRange.Value2 = header.ToArray();

    //export each row
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        exportRange = exportRange.get_Offset(1, 0);
        exportRange.Value2 = dr.ItemArray;
    }
}
```